# Baking diffuse of metallic materials

Tags: texture-baking, baking

I noticed that baking diffuse for a metallic material causes the result to be black. I'm assuming because metallic materials don't have a diffuse.
So, what is the best way to bake diffuse for metallic materials? The solution I came up with is to set the metallic of the original material to 0, bake using diffuse, and then add a metallic map.
Is there a better way than my current method, or is this how it's supposed to be done?

Comment: The correct "diffuse" for a metal is black. So I guess the question is, why is black not acceptable? What do you plan to do with this diffuse bake where you want non-black pixels on metal objects?

Comment: So your question is basically, "How should a specular/glossy material be baked?"

Comment: The reason I want to bake a metallic texture is because I have a high poly asset and a low poly asset and I want to bake the texture of the high poly asset onto the low poly asset.